# Selenium not updating current window

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webdriverwait

Selenium seems to be looking for data in an old page and not the new one.

I'm trying to automate a search where I select from a dropdown menu and fill a box with some value

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

url = 'http://www.op.nysed.gov/opsearches.htm'
value = '60'
license_no = '084157'

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)

select = Select(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//form[@id="licensee-num-form"]/center/select'))
select.select_by_value(value)

fill = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//form[@id="licensee-num-form"]/center/input')
fill.send_keys(license_no)
fill.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

data = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@id='content_column']")
```

However, when I print `data.text`, it prints data from the first page, not the second one. I tried using `driver.refresh()` to refresh the page but it did not work.

Comment: Please share ALL your code so we can understand what going on there. If possibly - including a link to the page you working on

Comment: @Prophet Hi, I updated my question with the code.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you getting the `data = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@id='content_column']")` immediately after clicking the `Enter`. The page still not refreshed. You should add a short delay there and then wait for element visibility on the refreshed page.
Please try this:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

url = 'http://www.op.nysed.gov/opsearches.htm'
value = '60'
license_no = '084157'

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
driver.get(url)

select = Select(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//form[@id="licensee-num-form"]/center/select'))
select.select_by_value(value)

fill = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//form[@id="licensee-num-form"]/center/input')
fill.send_keys(license_no)
fill.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
time.sleep(0.5)
data = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='content_column']")))
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! Unfortunately, it still gets the wrong data. I tried increasing the wait time, but that didn't help.